# How to connect AWS Glue Job with Aurora Serverless v2 PostgreSQL database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless, aws-glue-connection

I am trying to connect AWS Glue Job with Aurora Serverless v2 PostgreSQL database, placed in **isolated** subnet.

If someone did the same, I would really appreciate the correct steps and if someone can explain - is it posible to use IAM Role with `rds:connect` so Glue can access database?

I have followed AWS Documentation for setting up whe Glue Job in VPC.

- set up self-referencing security group
- created Connection in Glue with JDBC driver.
- In Connection, have set the Network and VPC.

Also, I have followed these steps on [post](https://repost.aws/questions/QUpkrhcfkYQtS2adbjpQ7quQ/cannot-connect-from-glue-to-rds-postgres#AN2SxYJ-3pT425XOS0GhUmQg) and hit the same error.